# How to refresh a table oj-table component in oracle-jet?

Tags: javascript, oracle-jet

I'm adding data to an API and i want that my oj-table display it. how to refresh a specific component in oracle-jet?

I am developing an application using oracle-jet v6.1.0, where i use local apis to get and store data and displays it using tables. I send the POST request and the data is stored in the database and in the callback function i go to the table page but I do not get the new rows!

This the function when i click the submit button:

```
   self.submitopportunity = function() {

        var dataObj = {
            "projectName": self.custProject(),
            "department": self.custDepartements(),
            "type": self.srtVal(),
            "budget": self.custBudget(),
            "description": self.solutionVal(),
            "closeDate": self.closeDate(),
            "customer": self.nameVal(),
            "product": self.productVal(),
            "status":  self.statusVal(),
            "contact": self.contactVal(),
            "favorite": false
        };
        console.info(dataObj);
        $.ajax({
            url: url + '/opportunity',
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(dataObj),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (response) {
                oj.Router.rootInstance.go("opportunities");
                return true;
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log("Something went wrong", error);
            }
        })

    };
```

When I refresh the page, the new lines are added. So how can I synchronize or refresh the oj-table component?

Answer (score 2):

All oracle JET components have a 'refresh' function. Just do this:

```
document.getElementById('yourtableid').refresh();
```

To update the component directly after navigating to the table page, you need to use the fact that `oj.Router`'s `go` method [returns a Promise](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jsdocs/oj.Router.html#go). We can use the callback to refresh the table.

```
success: function (response) {
      oj.Router.rootInstance.go("opportunities").then(
         function(result) {
            if (result.hasChanged) {
                document.getElementById('yourtableid').refresh();
            }
         },
         function(error) {
            console.log('Failed. ', error);
         }
      );
      return true;
 }
```

Comment: i did that with a button now but what am asking for is how to make run when i go from my form to my "opportunities" page. every time a navigate in the between the route the refresh is done automatically